# QListWidget: mutually exclusive checkboxes?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Is it somehow possible for the checkboxes of QListWidgetItems in a QListWidget to be mutually exclusive? Maybe with something like QButtonGroup? I haven't found anything yet.

I had another idea to just set the checkstate of every QListWidgetItem to false except the newly checked, via an itemChanged listener. But I don't how to get the item that triggered the signal.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itemChanged` is a correct approach, and you can get the item just from its argument.

In order to avoid recursion, you have to temporarily disconnect the signal from the function that actually checks the "exclusivity", set/unset the check states, and then reconnect afterwards.

```
class ExclusiveList(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.checkedRow = 0
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem('Item {}'.format(i + 1))
            item.setCheckState(
                QtCore.Qt.Checked if i == self.checkedRow else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.addItem(item)

        self.itemChanged.connect(self.checkExclusive)

    def checkExclusive(self, item):
        self.itemChanged.disconnect(self.checkExclusive)
        row = self.indexFromItem(item).row()
        if row != self.checkedRow:
            oldChecked = self.item(self.checkedRow)
            oldChecked.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.checkedRow = row
        elif not item.checkState():
            # avoid unchecking the current checked item, so that one item will 
            # *always* be checked
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        self.itemChanged.connect(self.checkExclusive)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm using now is a QScrollArea with a list of QRadioButtons in a QVBoxLayout. It may not be styled like a QListWidget, but it does what I need it to do.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QRadioButton, QButtonGroup, QScrollArea, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
import sys

class QRadioButtonListWidget(QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, inputList, signalConnect=None, parent=None):
        super(QRadioButtonListWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.inputList = inputList
        self.signalConnect = signalConnect

        self.initUI()

        if not signalConnect is None:
            self.btnGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.connector)

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.btnGroup = QButtonGroup()
        for i, elem in enumerate(self.inputList):
            btn = QRadioButton(str(elem))
            self.btnGroup.addButton(btn, i)
            layout.addWidget(btn)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWidget(widget)

    def connector(self, btn):
        self.signalConnect(self.btnGroup.id(btn))


def printId(id):
    print("id clicked: " + str(id))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QRadioButtonListWidget([1, 2, 3, "A", "B", "C"], printId)
w.show()
app.exec_()
```